# Android Up navigation: returning from child to parent activity selecting the correct fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, navigation

I have an app which has 3 sections in the navigation drawer, sections X, Y, Z, those sections are implemented each as a fragment, now I have 3 detail activities A, B, C, sections are related to these detail activities as follows X -> A, Y -> B, C -> Z, but there's the case that activity A has a link to activity B, and in a flow that goes A -> B, my up navigation in activity B should redirect to the parent showing the proper section, which in the case of B would be Y, is there a way to do this? I've defined my parent activity (drawer activity) for each detail activity, and the home button seems to be working, but I need to pass somehow an extra or something to that home button intent (I believe it must use some intent to open the parent activity), how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                upIntent.putExtra("OpenFragment", "YourFramentNumber");
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                return true;
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

get this intent in your Navigation Activity, and with a function make the transition to the required `Fragment` accordingly.